# Can I replace sugar with honey in baking?

Tags: substitutions, sugar, honey

Can I substitute honey for sugar in baked goods.If yes then how much honey would be equal to one cup of sugar?

Comment: Aggreed that it's a duplicate.  Maira, please see the answers to those two questions, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be. The general rule of thumb is to use half the amount of honey as you would cane sugar, reduce the other liquids by 1/4 cup, and add one 1/2 teaspoon of baking soda for every cup of honey used. I've done this with a couple different muffin recipes and had them turn out fine.

I've also combined honey with sugar substitutes (1:4 ratio) to use in place of brown sugar when baking for my diabetic father. When I do this, I don't eliminate any other liquids as the sugar substitutes tend to dry out baked goods.